# ValueChangeListener is not changing values in input text field and in dropdown

Tags: jsf-1.2

In my application, I call the value change listener on change of values in a listbox.
The value change listener should update the values of four fields - 2 input text fields and 2 combo boxes ( dropdown boxes). The bean scope is request. I am using JSF 1.2 version.

the jsp file:

```
<h:selectManyListbox id="FSIBUCKET" required="true" 
rendered="#{mangAreaSignOff.renderSelectedFSIBUCKET}"  
valueChangeListener="#{mangAreaSignOff.handleFSIBucketValueChange}" 
onchange="submit(); javascript:waiton();"  style="width:230px"value="#{mangAreaSignOff.selectedFsiBucket}" >

 <f:selectItems value="#{mangAreaSignOff.fsiBucketList}" />

</h:selectManyListbox>
```

the java code:

```
public void handleFSIBucketValueChange(ValueChangeEvent vce) 
{
    Object[] selectedFSIBucket = (Object[]) vce.getNewValue();
    setSelectedFsiBucket(selectedFSIBucket);
    getFSIBucketValueChangeResults();
}

public void getFSIBucketValueChangeResults() 
{
    Object [] tempFSIBucket = getSelectedFsiBucket() ;
    String FSIBucket =  getArrayToString(tempFSIBucket, ";");
    List<String> result = mangAreaAPI.getFSIBucketValueChanges(FSIBucket);
    mangAreaVO.setSelectedThresholdcategory(result.get(0));
    mangAreaVO.setSelectedThresholdAmount(result.get(1));
    mangAreaVO.setSelectedThresholdType(result.get(2));
    mangAreaVO.setSelectedThresholdPercent(result.get(3));
}
```

I need help to identify where the flow goes wrong.
On change of the listbox value, the 4 fields are not updated. In java class I am able to see the updated values. but in screen it is not updated. Please let me know if any more explanation is needed in my question.

```
     <h:panelGrid columns="10">
   .
  some other fields
   .
   .

                            <!-- Threshold Category -->
                            <h:panelGroup styleClass="text2"
                                rendered="#{mangAreaSignOff.renderInputThresholdCategory}">
                                <h:outputText value="MGT_LABEL_THRESHOLDCATEGORY" escape="false"
                                    converter="com.db.smis.planus.TermConverter" styleClass="text2" />
                                <f:verbatim>:</f:verbatim>
                            </h:panelGroup>
                            <h:panelGroup
                                rendered="#{!mangAreaSignOff.renderInputThresholdCategory}">
                                <h:outputText value="&#160;" escape="false" />
                            </h:panelGroup>

                            <!-- Threshold Amount -->
                            <h:panelGroup styleClass="text2"
                                rendered="#{mangAreaSignOff.renderInputAmount}">
                                <h:outputText value="MGT_LABEL_THRESHOLD" escape="false"
                                    converter="com.db.smis.planus.TermConverter" styleClass="text2" />
                                <f:verbatim>:</f:verbatim>
                            </h:panelGroup>
                            <h:panelGroup rendered="#{!mangAreaSignOff.renderInputAmount}">
                                <h:outputText value="&#160;" escape="false" />
                            </h:panelGroup>

                            <!-- Threshold Type -->
                            <h:panelGroup styleClass="text2"
                                rendered="#{mangAreaSignOff.renderThresholdType}">
                                <h:outputText value="MGT_LABEL_THRESHOLDTYPE" escape="false"
                                    converter="com.db.smis.planus.TermConverter" styleClass="text2" />
                                <f:verbatim>:</f:verbatim>
                            </h:panelGroup>

                            <h:panelGroup rendered="#{!mangAreaSignOff.renderThresholdType}">
                                <h:outputText value="&#160;" escape="false" />
                            </h:panelGroup>

                            <!-- Threshold Percentage -->
                            <h:panelGroup styleClass="text2"
                                rendered="#{mangAreaSignOff.renderThresholdPercent}">
                                <h:outputText value="MGT_LABEL_THRESHOLDPERCENT" escape="false"
                                    converter="com.db.smis.planus.TermConverter" styleClass="text2" />
                                <f:verbatim>:</f:verbatim>
                            </h:panelGroup>

                            <h:panelGroup
                                rendered="#{!mangAreaSignOff.renderThresholdPercent}">
                                <h:outputText value="&#160;" escape="false" />


    </h:panelGroup> 
    .
    .
    .
    .     

 </h:panelGrid>
```

I need to update the above 4 fields only.

Comment: You might have to `reRender` those fields. If those 4 fields into one panel , then `reRender` only that. If possible post those 4 fields code as well

Comment: If I am not wrong, `reRender` is ajax tag's attribute. But I am using JSF 1.2. So could u please give me some other way to achieve this.

Comment: Where are you displaying those 4 fields, if you give me the complete code, it would helpful to answer your question